# Test Built Python Package

Tags: python

So I recently built a Python package that required a few YAML files for configuration. Following the [distribution instructions](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html) I created a manifest file that looks like the following:

```
include LICENSE.txt
recursive-include thecurator *.yml *.csv *.json *.txt
```

According to the docs, I should have expected for the file to end up in the package... but it didn't, and after this screw up, I'm wondering how would I go about testing the built package against my pytest suite to make sure everything will work as expected after a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the manifest file is four source distributions. To include data files in built distributions you use the `package_data` option in the setup function.

```
setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={"mypackage": ["*.yaml"]},  # <- this
    test_suite="tests",
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    ...
    )
```

Comment: How can I actually test to ensure everything works at the distribution level though? My test suite and CI setup are a complete joke if mistakes like won't get caught.

Comment: You could just inspect the package (get a list of contents), and check that it's there. 
You could also take the built package and install it in a new place. A virtual environment would be good, such as `venv`. Then check for the files. But that's probably overkill.